# Why is the browser sorting in the following way

Tags: javascript, sorting, browser

I have following function:

```
var sortString = function (a, b) {
            a = a.toLowerCase();
            b = b.toLowerCase();
            if (a < b) return 1;
            if (a > b) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
```

and I have following two strings:

```
x = ["B1C3N_EUR_DFAK_ALL_3M_ALL","B1C3N_EUR_BPP_BCO_3M"];
```

When I run the above function on this array. I expect "B1C3N_EUR_BPP_BCO_3M" to be at index 0 whereas browser returns it in the reverse order. I have checked both on Chrome and IE. Why is it so??

Do I need to replace "-" with some other values. Is there any way I can do it without replacing.

Comment: This has to be a joke?

Comment: Nope..this ain't a joke. I have spent almost an hour figuring out way to sort it. Even if I replace `_` with from the string, it still somehow results in wrong sorting. The returning of 1 and -1 was mistake on my end while posting question, but even with that corrected I face the issue

Comment: Nope, you've messed up with your code (perhaps caching?), [which works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gf42v861/) when switching the place of the minus operator.

Comment: Yup buddy..U r right...Ashamed for such a blunder. Was looking for something in a entirely different file with similar name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return the wrong value for smaller and greater value in the callback for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

```
if (a < b) return 1;
//                ^  should be -1, because a is smaller than b

if (a > b) return -1;
//                ^^  should be 1, because a is greater than b
```

For a more concise style, you could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), which test the given strings and returns a value in the wanted range.

Comment: Using `localeCompare` would be good, too: `return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());`